# Difference in Converting Byte() to String

Tags: vb.net, encoding, byte, ascii

let us say I converted a photo to array of bytes by the following lines :

```
Dim Bytes() As Byte
Bytes = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\DT.jpg")
```

Now, the Bytes() could be converted to text and displayed in textbox via the code

```
TextBox1.Text = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Bytes)
```

the above line will print something like : 
9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2ODAp ...etc.

but 
when using the a function like

TextBox1.Text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Bytes)
the result is just : ???? (four question marks)

I worked around and made a loop

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Bytes.Length - 1
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Chr(bytes(I))
Next
```

and the textbox1 displayed something like : #3RðbrÑ $4á%ñ&'()*56789 ..etc
which is exactly the ASCII representation of each byte in the bytes().

my question is :
why it failed to return the ASCII, UTF8,UTF7, ANSI, etc representation of the Bytes using functions under namespace System.Text.Encoding. ? is there anyway to get the representation not by using the loop ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking but the data for an image is binary, not text.  I would not expect any GetString method to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it failed" and it "did not work".  Those aren't very specific descriptions of your problem and since we don't have access to the same binary data that you're using for input, we have no way to test or reproduce it.

Comment: Pretty sure that the Encoding.GetString() implementations you cite will either return a string (an empty string for a zero-length array) or throw ArgumentNullException, neither of which you are likely to call "failed to give a string". Please [edit] your question to clarify. Try giving sample input data, the expected result and the actual result from code you have tried.

Comment: I had already voted to close this question under a different reason, so not it's not allowing me to change my reason for closing it, so if someone else could please vote to to close it as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362493/ascii-getstring-stop-on-null-character), I'd appreciate it.  In light of the clarification of the question (provided as a non-answer answer below), the problem is not that it fails to decode as a string.  His problem is that he's trying to display a string containing null characters in a WinForm text box, so it's truncating.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update your answer with the additional details.  As you can see in my comment above, you are running into the same problems that others have asked about before.  WinForm text boxes automatically terminate displaying text at the first null character in a string (`Chr(0)`).  That's because the underlying windows desktop system was written written in C, where null terminated strings are common-place.  So, when you set the `Text` property to a long string containing some null characters, the textbox will only show the text up through the first null character.

Comment: Actually, `Chr(bytes(I))` will give you the ISO8859-1 representation. ASCII has only 128 characters. You might be interested in substituting control characters with [control picture](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf) characters. Note: JPEG does have a spec so if you are looking to display the text fields in a JPEG image, you might use that and certainly someone has done it before.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
Public Function ImageToBase64(image As Image, format As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat) As String
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        ' Convert Image to byte[]
        image.Save(ms, format)
        Dim imageBytes As Byte() = ms.ToArray()

        ' Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes)
        Return base64String
    End Using
End Function
```

and:

```
Public Function Base64ToImage(base64String As String) As Image
    ' Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)

    ' Convert byte[] to Image
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)
    Dim image__1 As Image = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
    Return image__1
End Function
```

Code stolen from here and converted to vb.net

http://www.dailycoding.com/posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx