# Response not showing in text visualizer

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I am working on a c# desktop application. I have a string in which I am encoding some bytes. While debugging it does show data in it but when I open text visualizer it is empty.

**Code**

```
 // String to store the response ASCII representation.
    string responseData = string.Empty;
NetworkStream stream = clientsocket.GetStream();
                stream.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
```

[image]

**Text Visualizer**

[image]

I don't know why it's happening. I must be doing something wrong

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: It starts with `\0`

Comment: ok so how can i set it ?

Comment: What do you mean? The string has a value, it's just that it starts with ascii character 0.

Comment: mean that how can i store it in a string then?

Comment: It is stored in a string. It's just not displayed after ASCII character 0.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362493/ascii-getstring-stop-on-null-character) may help you understand why it doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not use a string to store arbitrary binary data. If possible, you should e.g. use a byte-array.

If you must use a string, e.g. to transport your data over an API, you could use base64-encoding, to convert your data to a valid string.

```
string b64String = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```

Of course this means that the recipient of that string must convert it back to a byte-array. If that side of the transport is also C#, it might look like the following:

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(b64String);
```